# create a git branch based on a wrong branch how to make it right

Tags: git

On master branch, I do

```
git branch -b me
git add .
git commit
git push
```

Then I am told I should use branch A, what should I do to make it like I do the above commands on branch B?

```
git move what-I-do-on-me-branch-based-on-master to me-branch-based-on-B
```

I don't need it fancy, but I do need it safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to rebase your commits.

```
git checkout me
git rebase B
```

What `rebase` does is:

- it finds the newest common commit between `me` and `B`
- applies commits from `me` newer than the common commit to `B`'s tip
- sets `me` to point to the last applied commit

So it gets you from this situation:

```
me → O   O ← B
     |  /
     | /
     O ← master
     |
    ...
```

Into this:

```
me → O
     |
     |
     O ← B
     |
     |
     O ← master
     |
    ...
```

Note that this will change commit times to when you make the rebase. Commit hashes will change too. In addition conflicts may appear similar to merge commits, although conflict sides will be reversed.